# Viewing a question crashes Opera Mobile on Android

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web

Opening up a question page on any stack exchange site crashes Opera Mobile 12.10.9 on Android 2.3.

This used to work. I noticed the crashing yesterday.

The browser (com.opera.browser.classic) can be downloaded here: http://www.opera.com/mobile/operabrowser/android ([or here](ftp://ftp.opera.no/pub/opera/android/classic/))

Comment: I don't think that is something SE should fix, but let's see what they say.

Comment: I think this is Opera Mini, which is not supported by Stack Exchange

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's Opera Mobile ('Classic'), not Opera Mini.

Comment: Opera Mobile is not supported either.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reporting. Although we don't support Android 2.x anymore. However, I'm working on some fixes for those views so there's a chance your case gonna be fixed as well.

Comment: @Paweł Well, if you manage to reproduce the bug (optimally, isolate it too), please file a report at Opera's tracker. It might affect Opera on newer Androids too.